# Is there a text editor with columns instead of scrolling?

Tags: editor, text-editor

Is there a text editor which offers horizontal, rather than vertical, scrolling (showing two pages side by side)?

I currently use TextMate, but would switch to any editor which offers this layout.  I'm getting really bored of scrolling up and down, over and over.

I've attached a screenshot of MS Word, which has a side-by-side horizontal scroll view for documents longer than a page.

[image]

I want something like that, Any recommendations?

Comment: Retagged, the question isn't limited to any text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vim: `<Esc>:vsplit` will open a second column for the file.
[image: One file, two columns]
[image: zoomed in]

In all fairness, I should warn you that Vim has a steep learning curve, and will force you to wrap your head around new concepts like command mode / edit mode / visual mode. The results are definitely worth it, if you have the time to learn it.

Comment: Does the content of the first column stop where the second one starts? The question is about text editors that support page breaks.

Comment: No, not like a newspaper, my bad. When the Zebedee mentioned text editors, not word processors, I assumed that he was using it for writing code, not reading documents. However, LibreOffice does do that, I'll make a correct answer with a screenshot.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm after...for Sublime Text! Hopefully this will make its way into version 3. I've never been all that enamoured with vim's idiosyncrasies, and while I do want this feature, I don't think it's really worth the time investment.

Answer (score 4):

Emacs offers a follow-mode which you might find helpful ( see for instance here http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FollowMode).

A short description of how it is used and what it does:

You need to open a buffer in two windows and enter follow-mode using M-x follow-mode. This is actually a bit of a drawback, because you need to learn how to use emacs, if you don't know it already (imho learning how to use emacs is worth spending some time).

After entering follow-mode the second buffer will skip to the place where the first buffer ends, similar to the page-by-page view offered by Microsoft Word. Now if you move the cursor down one line at a time and you leave the first buffer window at the bottom, the cursor will appear at the top of the second. If you move further down and you are at the bottom of the second window, both buffers will scroll simultaneously, the same holds for page-wise scrolling using C-v and M-v.
If your monitor screen is wide enough, you can open a third window to further increase number of lines being displayed.

I have made a screenshot, which shows a text file opened in this mode: [Screenshot auf Follow mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wli5i.png)

Comment: Do you have a function that automatically opens a buffer in two windows and enters follow-mode?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have such a function, it should actually be easy to write one, I will try that later.

Comment: After writing my own function I found out that there is the function follow-delete-other-windows-and-split, which closes all other windows and opens the buffer in the leftmost window in follow-mode.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm, it seems you are looking for layout features which you aren't likely to find in a text editor. Text editors are generally line based and don't understand the concept of pages. Text editors do things like code folding and allow lines to be wrapped or not. That is why text editors scroll in the vertical direction. These factors would affect pagination.

The concept of a page (and being able to lay them out side by side) doesn't really exist unless you are using a presentation manager such as a word processor or a desktop publishing package.

Comment: Perhaps there are text editors that can be extended to add page breaks after a set number of lines, show the pages horizontally and scroll across the break. Emacs follow-mode comes close.

Comment: maybe if one would - like in the "old days" of computing - could rely on matrix displays which do display only a defined number of lines, e.g. 30 lines, and after that automatically a LINEBREAK character appears which then continues the text in another window and so on... in consequence each "page" would require a new window, and those windows would need to be jumped at via special commands. ("next window" - "previous window") - I don't know how many windows can be handled, if your document has hundred pages... handle hundred windows??

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I know exactly what you want. Does Sublime Text 2's two-column layout with File > New View Into File do what you want?

[image: sublimetext2]

A change on one side is reflected instantly in the other side, and you can scroll them independently. You can have up to four columns per window.

Comment: Tried out, looks like the same document in a second column, but not like real pagination across two columns.

Comment: What I'm after is a 'synchronised' version of this

Answer (score 0):

In [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) Writer, go to `View -> Zoom...` and set `Zoom factor` to `Fit width and height`, and set `View layout` to `Automatic`. You can also set the number of columns manually, and if you choose two columns, you can use `Book Mode`.

[image: Libreoffice Writer with columns]
[image: Zoom and view detail]

Comment: Question was about a text editor, not word processor. Thanks, though!

Answer (score -1):

With scroll-binding in vim, you can edit two files side by side: [scroll-binding in Vim](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/scrollbind-td1143143.html).

Show a text file with two columns in vim:  http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/View_text_file_in_two_columns